# boost.asio: async_read/async_write completion handler ordering

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Does boost.asio provide any guarantees on completion handler ordering?  I have initiated a single async_read & a single async_write operation.  I am using the epoll_reactor internally.  If the socket becomes both readable & writable simultaneously, will my read (or write) operation and hence completion handler be executed in a particular order always

Currently, reading the epoll_reactor.ipp:perform_io, that seems to be the case.  But does the ASIO documentation guarantee that?

Comment: It's not documented so I would strongly suggest not relying on it. It shouldn't matter though. by the time you get the first handler event, the second will already have been posted to the io_service. There's nothing you can do to stop it being executed.

Comment: In addition, if you have more than one thread running through the io_service, both handlers will execute simultaneously.

Comment: I am not using multiple threads.  Thanks for the answer anyway.  I was after the documentation

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee. Also, its better to not to rely on any such "ordering" things. This is big field for race conditions and other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Asio provides no guarantees as to the order in which completion handlers will be invoked.

The `io_service` currently makes no guarantees about the invocation order of handlers.  Thus, the `io_service` is free to choose an arbitrary order, even if underlying reactor implementation was known to perform operations and post completion handlers in a known order.  Currently, only a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) specifies guarantees to the order in which posted handlers execute, and it explicitly notes that the order of completion handlers is unspecified.

> **Order of handler invocation**
>
> Given:
>
> - a strand object `s`
> - an object `a` meeting completion handler requirements
> - an object `b` meeting completion handler requirements
>
> ...
>
> Note that in the following case:
>
> ```
> async_op_1(..., s.wrap(a));
> async_op_2(..., s.wrap(b));
> ```
>
> the completion of the first async operation will perform `s.dispatch(a)`, and the second will perform `s.dispatch(b)`, but the order in which those are performed is unspecified. That is, you cannot state whether one happens-before the other. Therefore [...] no ordering guarantee is made.