# Boost Thread Pool Execution Order guarantee

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool

When using boost::asio::thread_pool, is it guarantee that the order I post or dispatch the tasks is the order that they will be *started*?

For example, if I have a boost::asio::thread_pool of 10 threads, and I post/dispatch 15 long running tasks to that thread_pool, there should be 5 tasks waiting for an open thread.  Is it guaranteed that task 11 will be the next task to start after one of the first 10 threads, then task 12, and so on?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: [XY Problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What do you need the order for? Wouldn't order defeat the purpose of thread pools in one manner or another? For post and dispatch, they behave slightly differently, and mixing them cannot be guaranteed to preserve order.

Comment: That may be a hard question to answer. What does "started" mean? It's easy to ensure that task A will be picked from a queue before task B is picked if task A goes in to the queue before B goes in, but who's to say that some worker won't pick task A and then lose its time slice while another worker picks and "starts" task B?

Comment: Sounds like you need to establish dependencies between tasks where necessary. You can do that with [Intel TBB task scheduler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506294).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812329/85371

Comment: The thread pool is operating on data in parallel, but i need to make sure the order that i process the results of the workers is the order that i posted them. From the posted link from sehe, and the comment from Solomon Slow, i see that there is no guarantee and therefore will add logic around that.